# inconsistencies with production and development databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have inherited a rails project. I was just looking through the database in development and production and noticed that there was at least one column in the production db that is not in the development db. How could this happen? How can I remedy this?

Thanks

Comment: It happens. If you don't need this column, you can simply remove it. Maybe it was generated manually.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if a column has been added (or removed) outside of a migration.  It's probably nothing to worry about.